# Allocating a large 2D array of NumericVectors in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to allocate a large(ish) 2D array of NumericVectors (the total memory should only be around 16Mb barring overhead), but I get a stack overflow. Here is the smallest reproducible example I can come up with:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)
testfun = cxxfunction(
    signature(x="list"),
    body='using namespace std;
        vector<vector<NumericVector> > rs=as< vector<vector<NumericVector> > >( x );
        return wrap(rs);',
    plugin="Rcpp")
x=lapply(1:1000,function(g) lapply(1:1000, function(h) runif(3)))
testfun(x)
```

Profiling with gdb with only tells me that I am very deep in a libR.so recursion. Note that while here the arrays are rectangular so I could use a NumericMatrix instead in my actual problem they will be jagged. Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: A solution using the (fairly new) `ListOf<T>` template class:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)
testfun = cxxfunction(
  signature(x="list"),
  body='using namespace std;
        ListOf<ListOf<NumericVector> > rs=as< ListOf<ListOf<NumericVector> > >( x );
        return wrap(rs);',
  plugin="Rcpp")
x=lapply(1:1000,function(g) lapply(1:1000, function(h) runif(3)))
testfun(x)
```

We just replace any calls to `std::vector` with `Rcpp::ListOf` and, somewhat magically, it works. Best of all -- data is not copied here (assuming `x` really is a list of numeric vectors).

Comment: Hi Kevin - thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I still get the stack overflow with this approach (note that I don't get it with the smaller size 5x5 2D array you put here). I had tried something a little similar which was making a standard C 2D array on the stack, but again, no luck.

Comment: Can you try setting the stack size explicitly with `ulimit` before launching the accompanying R process?

Comment: If OP wants 'collections' of R vectors, why not as Rcpp::List around Rcpp::NumericVector?  Mixing STL vectors and R vectors seems a little dicey.

Comment: Good point -- and hey, we also have `ListOf<T>` to handle this sort of thing explicitly as well. Totally slipped my mind!

Comment: My solution currently is std::vector< Rcpp::List > of Rcpp::NumericVectors, so that I can get a single NumericVector out just as rs[i][j]. Thanks for the pointer to ListOf<T>, that's much nicer, ListOf< ListOf< NumericVector > > does everything I need. If you want to put that in the main answer I'll accept it. Dirk: I didn't want to use a straight List because then every time I want to get a single NumericVector out I would have to do something like as<List>((SEXP)rs[i])[j] which seems clunky.

Comment: Sure. Or just use `std::list<std::vector<double> >`.  Nice answer by Kevin though.